# using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement set metadata of large files upload

Tags: azure-storage

I am using Azure.Storage..Data Movement to upload large files to Storage account  in a ASp.net web form 4.5 . I dont see a way to set the metadata of uploaded blob options without getting reference. What is the best way to do it using this class. Blobcloudoptions has metadata option , but in TransferManager.UploadAsync(....).
Any pointer is appreciated.
Regards
Sunny

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). It may help others, and people like to help you when you can give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `TransferManager.UploadAsync()` method does not support `set metadata` directly. You can go through [the source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/lib/TransferManager.cs#L85) for more details.

Instead, we need to get a reference of the blob first -> then set the metadata -> then upload it via the `TransferManager.UploadAsync()` method. Like below:

```
        //other code

        //get a blob reference
        CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob.txt");

        //set metadata here
        destBlob.Metadata.Add("xxx", "yyy");


        //other code

        //then use the following method to upload file
        TransferManager.UploadAsync(xxx);
```